# BroadcastReceiver how often does it listen for Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am not sure if I got this right but the documentation says the BroadcastReceiver object is valid for the duration of the call to onReceive. Does it mean that after that the object is destroyed? Also the documentation indicates that the BroadcastReceiver is activated when it receives Intent. Does a BroadcastReceiver runs as some sort of service always listening for this sort of Intents? If so how often is that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523872/whats-broadcastreceiver-lifecycle-in-a-process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any broadcast receiver that is listed in the manifest is created by the system in response to an event that matches its intent filter. After it is done processing the intent, the instance of the broadcast receiver is destroyed. When another event happens, the system will create a new instance to handle it.